# Angular 2.2.0 platform-browser-dynamic bootstrap not found

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

i am used to import bootstrap by plattform-browser-dynamic 2.0.0
like this:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/';
```

Now i create new Projekt and use angular release 2.2.0
Plattform-browser-dynamic packages has version 2.2.0:

```
 "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.15"
```

I try same like with package 2.0.0 to import bootstrap, but it will not be found.
My code:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/*';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

ERROR:

error TS2305: Module '"../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index"' has no exported member 'bootstrap'.

How can i fix that? i cant find some similar lib.

Answer (score 4):

As per angular final release you can `bootstrap` your application module using `platformbrowser`'s `bootstrapModule` method. Additonally you need to create your own module for your App.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

[**Plunkr Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/E0VlJOXriU3Q8aMi07O4?p=preview)